# Java: Can't paint() every item from an array

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a game in which i need to paint bricks of a random color. This is my progress so far. I have a class of Brick, AllBricks, and Overridden paint method for `JPanel`:

```
private static class Brick {
    static int x;
    static int y;
    static Color color;

    Brick(int _x, int _y, Color _color){
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        color = _color;
    }

    void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRoundRect(x, y, BRICK_SIZE, BRICK_SIZE, BRICK_ARC_SIZE, BRICK_ARC_SIZE);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRoundRect(x + 1, y + 1, BRICK_SIZE-2, BRICK_SIZE-2, BRICK_ARC_SIZE-1, BRICK_ARC_SIZE-1);
    }
private static class AllBricks {
    private ArrayList<Brick> bList = new ArrayList<>();

    AllBricks(){ bList.clear(); }

    void add (Brick b){ bList.add(b); }

    void paint(Graphics g) {
        if(bList.size()>0) {
            for (Brick brick : bList) brick.paint(g);
        }
    }
}
private static class GameField extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        allBricks.paint(g);
    }
}
```

And now, when I call my main loop, adding new blocks and trying to draw them, i only see the last added block, but not all of them...

```
private void loop()
{
    while (true) {
        delay.wait(1000);

        Brick b1 = new Brick(random.nextInt(WIN_WIDTH - BRICK_SIZE), random.nextInt(WIN_HEIGHT - BRICK_SIZE), COLORS.get(random.nextInt(COLORS.size() - 1)));
        allBricks.add(b1);
        mainField.repaint();
    }
}
```

Can you, please, help me save previously painted blocks on the screen?

Comment: `Can you, please, help me save previously painted blocks on the screen?` - you need to repaint all the bricks each time the component is repainted. Also, you should be overriding `paintComponent(...)` of the panel, not paint(). The other option is to paint to a `BufferedImage`. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for more information and working examples on this topic.

Comment: Now as i'm overriding paintComponent - nothing changes.. and yes, i call allBlocks.paint() method which iterates through all blocks in array, and call it's .paint();

Comment: I know nothing changes you still need to modify your code. You missed my first statement which is the most important!!! You also missed the point about reading the information found in the link.

Comment: that's my question - how else could i repaint 'em all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brick x and y coordinate shoudn't be static. Since it's static all Bricks have one shared x and y value (so all Bricks are drawn at the same position)